# Cambiar valor de un campo con un trigger segun fecha y dia

Tags: mysql, trigger

tengo un campo en una tabla de mi base de datos que indica el estado de un producto (activo 1, vencido 2, estos son de tipo boolean) y un campo con la fecha de vencimiento (de tipo date) entonces necesito crear un disparador que día a día verifique si la fecha actual (del servidor) es menor a la fecha_vencimiento y en caso de ser verdad (es decir si se cumple esa condición el producto estaría vencido) cambiar el estado a valor 2 (vencido)

Como podria plantear el disparador en MYSQL?

Estoy intentando con un evento::

```
DROP EVENT `desactivaCotizacon`; 
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` EVENT `desactivaCotizacon`
   ON SCHEDULE EVERY 3 MINUTE STARTS '2021-06-26 18:41:48' 
   ON COMPLETION PRESERVE 
   ENABLE 
   DO 
      UPDATE cotizacions 
        SET status = '1' 
        WHERE fecha_vencimiento > DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y%m%d')
```

El script no lanza errores pero no hace el update en ningun momento

Saludos a todos

Comment: Revisa el [*Planificador de eventos*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/events-overview.html) de MySQL o los *crons* de Linux o el *Programador de tareas* de Windows.

Comment: edite la pregunta con el script que estoy probando pero no me funciona

Comment: hice una prueba colocando una fecha manual para hacer la comparacion y funciono, pero lo que necesito es que compare con la fecha actual (es decir con el dia de hoy)

Comment: fecha_vencimiento es date, si te fijas habia probado con DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y%m%d') para obtener la fecha actual ( o sea el dia de hoy) pero no me resulto, coloque la fecha manual y ahi si funciono el evento

Comment: Prueba con `fecha_vencimiento > curdate()`. Aunque creo que debería ser `>=`.

Comment: No existe el número 2 en el tipo de dato Boolean, el tipo de dato Boolean (o Tiny) en MySQL solo tiene como valor 0 y 1

Comment: @Fernando: Querrás decir BIT; no hay Tiny, sino Tinyint que va de -128 a 127, y por cierto, Bit puede almacenar hasta 64 bits.

Comment: @Sal Mi punto estaba mal planteado, lo que quise decir era de que si vamos a hablar de un tipo de dato Booleano, o es 0 o es 1 de manera lógica, no debería de ser ni 2, ni 4, ni 10.

Comment: no me resulto con curdate() tampoco